# How to reach a specific item in the array object in python

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have npy file which seems it is a numpy.ndarray, (array of object), I want to reach the values for a specific item. How can I do it?
This picture shows a part of npy file content and for example I have to reach values for avgmotion:

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb4re.png)

Comment: Hi @Faezeh Rabbani, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of posting a screenshot, please create a Minimum Reproducible Example of your question. Refer to the docs here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I found my answer here
[Extract dictionary item from numpy ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572753/extract-dictionary-item-from-numpy-ndarray)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the variable you're using is a dictionary.

You have to access to the values of the key : *avgmotion* by simply putting the information in variable, let's assume your dictionary's variable is *name_of_dict*.

```
   avgmotion = name_of_dict["avgmotion"]
```

After that you can check the shape and size of your array and try to extract whatever data you want.

Comment: this method showes me this error=>     IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices